# XAMPP WordPress fresh "re-install" - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: database, wordpress, xampp

So, I mucked things up pretty good. I've researched this topic, but none of the solutions I found work or quite fit my situation.

Let me explain. I had somehow managed to get a local install of WordPress using Xampp onto my Win10 PC. I remember it was a struggle then and that was a week ago. Problem is that I forgot my admin password and I couldn't figure out a way around it. So...

1. I did a database drop in phpmysql and recreated the wp table.
2. I copied the wp_config.php file into a safe place.
3. I deleted the wordpress folder in c:/xampp/htdocs.
4. I downloaded a fresh copy of WordPress and extracted it to c:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress.
5. I copied the old wp_config.php file into the newly re-created folder.
6. I ran WordPress install and got to the screen where it says it's installed and here's your user name.
7. I clicked on the link to the Login screen.

That's when I got the message -- Error establishing a database connection.

I'm not sure how that's possible considering it was just connected and created all the tables in the database.

Here's what's in my wp_config.php file, though I'm not sure what could be wrong with it since it was working fine a second ago (:{):

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wp');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

I'm sure someone can tell me where I went wrong and hopefully how to fix it. I'm fine with starting over again. I just want to get it installed so I can learn the inner-workings. ;P

Thanks in advance. I look forward to learning from you all.
Jen

Comment: it seems you made the installation complex instead of changing the administrator password from database. you reinstalled the wordpress after creating the wp_tables again it will not install properly bcz already tables exists

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I ended up uninstalling Xampp and re-installing it in order to resolve this.